# How to bottom align text in a textbox control in pdf file using itextsharp

Tags: c#, .net, itext

I need to bottom align text which I'm getting from *TextBox* in PDF file.

I'm using below code to get text from *TextBox* in pdf.

```
 for (int i = 1; i <= reader.NumberOfPages; i++)
        {

            iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfArray array = reader.GetPageN(i).GetAsArray(iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfName.ANNOTS);
            if (array == null) continue;
            for (int j = 0; j < array.Size; j++)
            {
                iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfDictionary annot = array.GetAsDict(j);

                iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfString text = annot.GetAsString(iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfName.CONTENTS);

            }
        }
```

I'm using *ItextSharp* Library. Error screenshot

[image]

Comment: From your screen shot, I can tell that you have Adobe Acrobat. Please take a look at the tabs "Appearance", "Position" and "Options". Do you see an option that allows you to bottom align the text? No, you only see the option to horizontally align the text (Left, Center, Right). If you can not set a value in Adobe Acrobat to bottom align the content of a text field, you should not expect it to be possible with any other software.

Answer (score 1):

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(SOURCE); 
PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, TARGET); 

TextField tf = new TextField(stamper.getWriter(), new Rectangle(300, 400, 
500, 420), text);
stamper.addAnnotation(tf.getTextField(), 1);

PdfContentByte overContent = stamper.getOverContent(1);
BaseFont baseFont = BaseFont.createFont();
overContent.setFontAndSize(baseFont, 12);
overContent.beginText();
overContent.showTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_BOTTOM, text, 300,
405, 0);
overContent.endText();
stamper.close ();
```

or try this also

```
using (PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(new PdfReader(inputFile), File.Create(outputFile)))
{
TextField tf = new TextField(stamper.Writer, new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(0, 0, 100, 300), "Vertical");
stamper.AddAnnotation(tf.GetTextField(), 1);
}
```

Comment: @Ashwani, Was it helpful??

Comment: @Ashwani,Let me know how you declared textfield in program

Comment: @Ashwani,is your textfield placed in a pdfcell? Then have a look on my edited answer

Comment: i'm not sure whether its under pdfcell, can you pls tell me if i need to get text values from textfield?

Comment: @Ashwani, Actually what do you mean by textfield.Let me see how it declare in your project.. Show me your text field

Comment: pls see my updated question with screenshot. i took it from acrobat reader.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74075/discussion-between-ashwani-and-semil-sebastian).